# How to validate Hashed SHA1 password using sha256

Tags: javascript, hash, sha256, sha

I am trying to convert sha1 hashed password to sha256 hashed password. Can you please guide me how this can be achieved using javascript. I am basically having some sha1 hash passwords which needs to be validated. However, the application only supports sha256.

Comment: You would need the original password and just rehash it with SHA256.

Comment: When you say "convert sha1 to sha256", what specifically are you trying to do?  If you want to take the current hash as a string and she256-hash it, what prevents you?  If you want to retrieve the *original password* and hash that, you can't.  That's the point of hashing it in the first place.  The person who knows the password would have to provide it.

Comment: Ideally though, you wouldn't even think of using SHA256 to hash passwords and use a modern secure hashing algorithm like BCrypt or Argon2.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly. Hashing functions are designed to be used in only one direction (plain password -> hashed password). There is no way to retrieve the original password from hashed password or to convert a hashed password to use another hashing function without knowing the original password in first place.

Comment: *...no way ... to convert a hashed password to use another hashing function...*  Yes, there is a way. If you're new hashing algorithm is, say argon2(sha1(password)) then you don't the original password.